# Tron Web - Validate TransferContract error, no OwnerAccount (Tron Link)

Tags: blockchain, solidity, tron, tronweb, tronlink

I am developing a block chain web application using Tron Web. I have followed the document but getting below error while using tronweb.trx.sign() function,

> Uncaught (in promise) class
> org.tron.core.exception.ContractValidateException : Validate
> TransferContract error, no OwnerAccount.

Below is my code, (I have tron link chrome extension, Node: Mainnet)

```
var obj = setInterval(async () => {
            if (window.tronWeb && window.tronWeb.defaultAddress.base58) {
                clearInterval(obj)
                var tronweb = window.tronWeb
                var tx = await tronweb.transactionBuilder.sendTrx('fromaddr', 10, 'toaddr');
                var signedTx = await tronweb.trx.sign(tx);
                var broastTx = await tronweb.trx.sendRawTransaction(signedTx);
                console.log(broastTx)
            }
        }, 10)
```

Kindly check and let me know what am i missing

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `'fromaddr'` with `'toaddr'`

```
var obj = setInterval(async () => {
            if (window.tronWeb && window.tronWeb.defaultAddress.base58) {
                clearInterval(obj)
                var tronweb = window.tronWeb
                var tx = await tronweb.transactionBuilder.sendTrx('toaddr', 10, 'fromaddr');
                var signedTx = await tronweb.trx.sign(tx);
                var broastTx = await tronweb.trx.sendRawTransaction(signedTx);
                console.log(broastTx)
            }
        }, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line, the first and third argument are string literals and not object.

```
var tx = await tronweb.transactionBuilder.sendTrx('fromaddr', 10, 'toaddr');
```

From the [docs](https://developers.tron.network/docs/trx-transfer) , first and third argument are addresses.

```
await tronWeb.transactionBuilder.sendTrx(
      toAddress,
      amount,
      fromAddress
);
```

Note: Tron addresses are available in Hex and and Base format. To convert one format to one another you can use `tronWeb.address.toHex(address)` or `tronWeb.address.fromHex(address)`

Comment: The addresses are supposed to be strings, not objects (well, strings are objects, but not some kind of TronWeb object), as the docs you link to show.